# Why does solving the spherical Bessel equation using Frobenius series produce two quadratic equations for the exponents at the singularity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

The spherical Bessel equation is:
    $$x^2y'' + 2xy' + (x^2 - \frac{5}{16})y = 0$$

If I seek a Frobenius series solution, I will have:
    \begin{align*}
        &\quad y = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_nx^{n + r} \\
        &\implies y' = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (n + r)a_nx^{n + r - 1} \\
        &\implies y'' = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (n + r)(n + r - 1)a_nx^{n + r - 2}
    \end{align*}
Substituting into the ODE of interest:
    \begin{align*}
        &\quad x^2y'' + 2xy' + (x^2 - \frac{5}{16})y = 0 \\
        &\equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (n + r)(n + r - 1)a_nx^{n + r} + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 2(n + r)a_nx^{n + r} + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_nx^{n + r + 2} + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{-5}{16}a_nx^{n + r} = 0 \\
        &\equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} [(n + r)(n + r - 1) + 2(n + r) - \frac{5}{16}]a_nx^{n + r} + \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} a_{n - 2}x^{n + r} = 0 \\
        &\equiv [r(r-1) + 2r - (5/16)]a_0 + [(r+1)(r) + 2(r+1) - (5/16)]a_1 + \\
        &\quad \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} ([(n + r)(n + r - 1) + 2(n + r) - \frac{5}{16}]a_n + a_{n-2})x^{n + r} = 0 \\
        &\implies [r(r-1) + 2r - (5/16)] = 0 \wedge  \\
        &\quad [(r+1)(r) + 2(r+1) - (5/16)] = 0 \wedge \\
        &\quad [(n + r)(n + r - 1) + 2(n + r) - \frac{5}{16}]a_n + a_{n-2} = 0
    \end{align*}

The first conjunct is the standard indicial equation specifying $r$. The second conjunct is yet another quadratic that $r$ has to satisfy. Is there a mistake? Or should $a_1 = 0$?

Comment: see below for a revised response to your concern

Answer (score 1):

The main indicial is the the first equation. You get two roots from the first equation so you should set $a_1=0$. If there is a common root between the first and second equations, then you can consider that root and set both $a_1$ and $a_0$ nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

You set the value of $r$ found in the first equation into the second equation. It then  defines $a_n$ in terms of $a_{n-2}$ for all $n \geq 2$. So, once we know $a_0$, $a_1$ we get $a_2$ from the second equation and so on.

Comment: Not true, the second conjunct states $[(r+1)(r) + 2(r+1) - (5/16)]a_1 = 0$. Its the third conjunct that is the recurrence relationship you are talking about. "Conjuncts" are the operands of the "and" operator: $\wedge$.

Comment: The second relation isn't a "conjunct" or another "indicial equation"  it is simply another equation that forces $a_1=0$ once you find the $r$-value from the indicial equation (the first one). The point is that $a_0\neq 0$ necessarily, or else all your solutions would have the property that $y(0)=0$. Thus the first one defines the $r$-values not the second.

Comment: Why is it not a conjunct?

Comment: If by a conjunct you mean an additional "indicial equation" then unless the roots are the same that can't happen. I mean we have a second order equation and so there two independent solutions that are found by solving the first quadratic. Those roots are then used in the second expression to force $a_1=0$ in this case. You then iterate to get the other terms.

Comment: A "conjunct" is an operand of the "and" ($\wedge$) operator. Every conjunct in an expression has to be a theorem ("true"), for the expression itself to be a theorem ("true"). Nowhere do I state that it might be *another* indicial equation, since *both equations cannot be satisfied*. Hence, I wondered if there was a mistake in my steps or whether the second conjunct should be interpreted as forcing $a_1 = 0$.  Your answer does not answer my question, and instead simply states a known fact *which was not my point of concern*.

Comment: what you are writing is called a "conjunction". I believe I answered your question as $a_1=0$ is necessary for the reasons stated.

Comment: [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction): look for the line that begins with: "An operand of a conjunction is called a...". I don't want to argue with you if you think your answer is sufficient. I disagree, and will leave it unmarked.

Comment: Forget it, I'm not spending any more time on this question.